# Posting to Facebook Group with FB GRAPH API

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, facebook-graph-api-v2.5

I have issue with posting to Facebook group with FB API.

So I have user authenticated with permissions:

```
email,
publish_pages,
publish_actions,
public_profile,
manage_pages,
read_insights,
user_managed_groups
```

I got access token then exchanged it to long lived access token which I am using then to post to FB Group.

SO I am calling API:

```
 GET /v2.5/{group-id}/feed
```

with next parameters for post:

```
parameters["message"]
parameters["caption"]
parameters["description"]
parameters["link"]
parameters["name"]
parameters["picture"]
```

Post is published to the FB group, but only the user which Access token is used can see it. The other members cannot see the post, but they got notification when post is published. So they got notification but when they click on the notification there is no post. The user which access token I am using is administrator of the group and only he can see the post, not even other administrators can see the post.

Tried also with sending these params as well on posting:

```
parameters["is_hidden"] = false
parameters["is_published"] = true
```

But the result is the same.

Does anyone have idea what is happening.

The option "Post Approval: All group posts must be approved by an admin." is unchecked so admin don't need to approve the post.

Comment: Most likely your app is not set “live” yet. It needs to be, otherwise all content created through it will only be visible to people with a role in the app.

Comment: @CBroe Yeap, that was the issue, the API was not set "live". Thank you, Can you put it as the answer so I can mark it as correct answer.

Comment: Hi, do I need to be a admin of the group to make a post in the group?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your app was not set “live” yet.

It needs to be, otherwise all content created through it will only be visible to people with a role in the app.

Comment: I am looking to post in a group as in the question but I am not the admin of the group. Can I still post into group?

Comment: @kittu: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.9/group/feed#publish explains under what circumstance you can post to a group.